# How to make mod_rewrite *not* perform home directory expansion when using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, vhosts

Filepath: `/Users/user_name/Sites/example.com`

Browseable at: `http://localhost/~user_name/example.com/`

In a child directory (`chrome`) I got a `.htaccess` like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^rgba\((\d{1,3}%?,\s?\d{1,3}%?,\s?\d{1,3}%?,\s?[0-1]?\.?\d+)\)$ rgba.php?rgba=$1 [PT]
```

This matches a request like:

```
http://localhost/~user_name/example.com/chrome/rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
```

and should rewrite the request to:

```
http://localhost/~user_name/example.com/chrome/rgba.php?rgba=(255,255,255,0.5)
```

I put the rgba.php in the `chrome` directory. Still I get this error msg:

```
The requested URL /Users/user_name/Sites/example.com/chrome/rgba.php was not found on this server.
```

I read the part in the manual about Home directory expansion and the [PT] flag but it makes no difference.

If i put up a vhost pointing to the `example.com` directory it works. I would like it to work both ways =P

So how do I do it?

I run Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) on a Mac OS X

**EDIT**
`AllowOverride` is set to `All` for the users `Sites` directory. If it wasn´t the rewrite shouldn´t have worked at all.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Any chance that you happened to find a fix to this?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda and OP, check my answer. Hopefully it helps you, or at least someone else.

Comment: Downvoter - care to explain why you chose to downvote this?

Answer (score 1):

I spent half a day wracking my brains on this and the only solution I could find was to create a new VirtualHost with the DocumentRoot set to the user's home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Holy god that was frustrating. But I have it working.

I tried a bunch of stuff. I *thought* that the PT flag on the RewriteRule would fix it, but nope.

I still don't know how to stop the home directory expansion, but I figured out a workaround. Just before the `RewriteRule`, use `RewriteBase /~user_name/example.com/chrome/`. This overrides the rewrite's prefix (log entry from my config):

```
<SNIP> (2) [perdir /Users/colin/Sites/ajaxtest/] trying to replace prefix /Users/colin/Sites/ajaxtest/ with /~colin/ajaxtest/
```

**UPDATE**

This solution works somewhat, but it appears to make the rewrite engine trigger twice... once for the internal redirect, and again afterwards. I ended up just using a VirtualHost like the other submitter.

Answer (score -1):

Allow overrides in you configuration file for your home directories.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Allowing overrides also does not solve it.